# How to check if an array is 2D

Tags: python, numpy

I read from a file with `loadtxt` like this

```
data = loadtxt(filename) # id x1 y1 x2 y2
```

`data` could look like

```
array([[   4.      ,  104.442848, -130.422137,  104.442848,  130.422137],
   [   5.      ,    1.      ,    2.      ,    3.      ,    4.      ]])
```

I can then reduce `data` to the lines belonging to some `id` number:

```
d = data [ data[:,0] == id]
```

The problem here is when the data contain only one line.

So my question is how to check the 2-dimensionality of my array `data`?

I tried checking

```
data.shape[0]  # num of lines
```

but for one-liners I get something like `(n, )`, so this will not work.

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[data.ndim](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html) gives the dimension (what numpy calls the number of `axes`) of the array.

---

As you already have observed, when a data file only has one line, `np.loadtxt`
returns a 1D-array.  When the data file has more than one line, `np.loadtxt`
returns a 2D-array.

The easiest way to ensure `data` is 2D is to pass `ndmin=2` to `loadtxt`:

```
data = np.loadtxt(filename, ndmin=2)
```

The `ndmin` parameter was added in NumPy version 1.6.0. For older versions,
you could use [np.atleast_2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html):

```
data = np.atleast_2d(np.loadtxt(filename))
```

---

Comment: Wow 50 secs to get an answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the dimension of your array with `len(array)` function.

**Example1:**

```
data = [[1,2],[3,4]]
if len(data) == 1:
   print('1-D array')
if len(data) == 2:
   print('2-D array')
if len(data) == 3:
   print('3-D array')
```

**Output:**

```
2-D array
```

And if your array is a **Numpy array** you can check dimension with `len(array.shape)`.

**Example2:**

```
import Numpy as np
data = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]])
if len(data.shape) == 1:
   print('1-D array')
if len(data.shape) == 2:
   print('2-D array')
if len(data.shape) == 3:
   print('3-D array')
```

**Output:**

```
2-D array
```

Comment: Example 1 does not work as you state.  The Output of Example 2 would actually be "1-D array".  It would have to be a recursive loop function to find the dimension of the array.  You'd also have to check every element to determine the full dimensions, as data[0] could technically vary in length from data[1].

Comment: Example 1 is plain wrong. It happens to output 2 because the length of the outer array is 2, not because it's a 2-D array.

Answer (score 0):

one more way:

Look for array.shape:

if it comes like (2,) means digit at first place but nothing after after comma,its 1D.
Else if it comes like (2,10) means two digits with comma,its 2D.
Similarly how many digits available with comma, that many dimensional array it is.

Simple "array.shape" will help you know that.